# Facebook Application/ Tab application session

Tags: database, facebook

I've got an application that exists primarily for use as a tab, with the canvas page acting as a control panel. When a user authorizes the tab for their page, Facebook redirects to the page url (e.g. http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGE-NAME … nstalled=1) with the Wall visible, but I would like it to redirect to the canvas page (e.g. http://apps.facebook.com/APP-NAME/?fb_p … nstalled=1). My reason for this is that I need the fb_page_id so I can link the page installed to their saved settings on my end.

Is there some setting I need to change to enable it, or FBML to add to the tab? You can see a working model of this by installing an Involver tab (http://involver.com/), as the app will automatically redirect to the canvas page with both the fb_page_id and installed variables.

Thanks!